# VS Code reporting on false positive on inherited method from parent class on PHP

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I have 2 classes, one is a parent and one is a child class. The problem arises whenever i try chaining a method from my child class with the methods from the parent class. VS code is reporting a false positive.

```
class BaseClass
{
protected $agent;

protected $report;

public function __construct()
{
    
}

public function setAgent($agent) : self
{
    $this->agent = $agent;

    return $this;
}

public function setReport($report) : self
{
    $this->report = $report;

    return $this;
}

public function getAgent() : User
{
    return $this->agent;
}

public function getReport()
{
    return $this->report;
}
}
```

and here is the child class:

```
  class ChildClass extends BaseClass
  {
    public function __construct()
    {
        
    }

    public function process(string $status)
    {
        //some code here
    }
   }
```

Here is how i call it:

```
    $child = new ChildClass();
    $child->setAgent($this->user)
                  ->setReport($this->report)
                  ->process($status);
```

VS Code is reporting that the method process() is undefined and underlines it with red. The code works fine both in usage and in tests. It just bothers me to see red lines and false positive in VS Code. Is there a way on how to fix this on VS Code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[You need to return static](https://github.com/phpstan/phpstan/issues/3141#issuecomment-607954870):

```php
    /**
     * @return static
     */
    public function setAgent($agent): self
    {
        $this->agent = $agent;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return static
     */
    public function setReport($report): self
    {
        $this->report = $report;

        return $this;
    }
```

But after all this does depend on your code-linter.

Comment: this solved my problem. any other explanation other than it's a problem with phpstan?

Comment: When you're returning `self` it's an instance of the class where the method is written (in your case `BaseClass`). If you return `static` it refers to whatever class in the hierarchy you called the method on (in your case `new ChildClass`.